# How to get textView data in UIPickerView of another ViewController

Tags: iphone

hai
   How to get the textView data in UIPickerView. UIPickerView is in another ViewController and it is a mutablearray. Can anyone help me? Help with some code or tutorial. please..
Thank you

Comment: Normaly,we will show rowwise data in UIPickerview.Why do you want to show UITextview data in UIPickerview?because UITextview is used to show paragraph data?

Comment: when the user write a message in textview and press ok button. The message should go in the UIPicker. This is what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create a method in the viewController that is containing that UIPickerView and call that method whenever the ok button is pressed sending the text string as a parameter, and then in that method, the picker's viewController can populate its field with the sent text?

Answer (score 0):

You can have 1 NSString property in another ViewController. 1 Method to assign textView data in that. like

> - @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *yourString; and Synthesize it.

```
-(void) contentToDisplay: (NSString *)yourContent{
    self.yourString = yourContent;
}
```

While switching to another ViewController use its object to assign text like [objViewController contentToDisplay:yourText];

hope this helps.